# How to access values in object on a related foreign key inDjango templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my model LineItems are related to JournalEntries by foreign key (JournalEntry has many LineItems).

In my template I've written the following code which loops through all my JournalEntries showing the LineItems that belong to each one:

```
    <ul>
        {% for journal_entry in journal_entries %}
            <li>{{ journal_entry.id }} - {{ journal_entry.description}}</li>
                <ul>
                    {% for line_item in journal_entry.lineitem_set.all %}
                        <li>{{line_item.id}} - {{line_item.description }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

But what I actually need is to is display each Journal Entry and the descriptions from its first and second LineItem all on one line. The code below doesn't work but it might show you what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{% for journal_entry in journal_entries %}
<li>{{ journal_entry.id }} - {{ journal_entry.line_item.1.description }} - - {{ journal_entry.line_item.2.description }}</li>
```

Comment: Why does your template not work? BTW indexing starts at "0" so you should be using `journal_entry.line_item.all.0` and `journal_entry.line_item.all.1`

Comment: If you need a custom string, wouldn't be easier to handle that at the view and just pass the required string as a context variable?